# AS3 Standing Wave Library Complete Event Not Firing

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the AS3 Library StandingWave and trying to get the "COMPLETE" event to fire for the audio player. I have the code below and the event never seems to fire. I do not get the trace not the button re-enabled.

```
var player:AudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSinewave);

function playSinewave(e:Event):void{
var sinewave:IAudioSource = new SineSource(new AudioDescriptor(),5,440,0.2);
play_btn.enabled = false;
player.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doComplete);
player.play(sinewave);
}

function doComplete(e:Event):void{
trace("COMPLETE")
play_btn.enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that player.play(sinewave); does not trigger Event.COMPLETE. I think it may trigger SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA. Event.COMPLETE is triggered when a sound source is loaded. The following bit of code should help:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Load the song.
var song:Sound = new Sound();
var songChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

song.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, hdSongLoaded);
song.load(new URLRequest("assets/songs/VMBach.mp3"));

//Buttons
buttons.onBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hdSoundOn);
buttons.offBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hdSoundOff);
buttons.skipBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hdSkip);

//Handlers.
function hdSongLoaded(e:Event) {
    //e.currentTarget.play();
    songChannel = song.play();
}

function hdSoundOn(e:MouseEvent) {
    songChannel = song.play();
}

function hdSoundOff(e:MouseEvent) {
    songChannel.stop();
}

function hdSkip(e:MouseEvent) {
    //removeChild(onBTN);
    //removeChild(offBTN);
    removeChild(buttons);
    songChannel.stop();
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

stop();
```